# ldf is not supported

Tags: anaconda, ldf, asammdf

I install asammdf package to read dat file in python. After installing asammdf using `pip install asammdf`, the installation is successful. However, when I import asammdf, I got `ldf is not supported`.
May I know how to solve this issue and after installing the asammdf? Moreover I also cannot open the spyder in my anaconda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just a warning message from the canmatrix library. If you don't use LIN database file (ldf files) for bus logging decoding then you can just ignore it.

If you really want to make it go away then just install the ldfparser package since this is required for ldf support ( see
https://github.com/ebroecker/canmatrix/blob/6ed291b73a5824e367615c99ee1b4e6084eb026e/setup.py#L98)

Comment: After installing the asammdf package in anaconda, I cannot open the spyder. I am not sure whether cannot open spyder is related to the asammdf package.